# Autolayout constraints boundary condition

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, ios-autolayout

I want view1 right constraint to be equal to view2 left constraint, but not if view2 moves past left of view1 (boundary condition). Here are the constraints I have:

```
    view1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    view1.leftAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingAfter: contentView.leftAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true


   let rightBoundaryConstraint = view1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iew2.leftAnchor)

    rightBoundaryConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(999)
    rightBoundaryConstraint.isActive = true
```

My doubt is this still does not determine position of view1 with 100% certainty. Am I missing something?

Comment: A side note: you ask a lot of questions, but rarely accept an answer... Do you not get much help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This says "expand or contract view1 so its right-edge is at the left-edge of view2":

```
view1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view2.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

add this:

```
view2.leftAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view1.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

which says: "Don't let view2's left-edge go past view1's left edge"